# No value when document isn't found in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

right now I have code that works to get information from different workbooks into one master excel. However, when the document is not found it gives a #NAME error which is affecting a table that I need to present that data. I was trying to write if statements to fix this but have not been successful, I also tried to not make it by cell name but just the cell itself but got a #VALUE error. Is there a way to make that value blank if the document is not found? 
Thanks for the help. 
This is the code I have:

```
Sub ROI()

 Dim JobNumber As String
 Dim srcCell As String

 Dim id As Integer

   For id = 4 To 156
       srcCell = "C" & id

       JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value

       Range("D" & id).Value = "='Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Total"
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a **Sub** not a **Function** that would return the `#name!` ERROR.

Comment: So if I change it to a function it should work correctly? or will that ruin the rest of the code? Sorry I am a bit new to VBA.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong here not the least of which is that you have to open a worksheet before retrieving any information. However, some native worksheet functions will do that (by opening, retrieving and closing the worksheet for you).

Comment: At the moment this code takes the information from the worksheets on its own, all I have to do is run the macro from the developer tab. I dont actually have to open the worksheets, they just need to be saved in that folder referenced in the path. Any tips on how to make it work so that they stay blank when the file does not exist?

Comment: If you think you are taking information from a closed workbook then you are wrong. It is only at the level of overhead the opening and closing of the workbook this occurs.

Comment: Is it possible to do what I want with basic VBA knowledge? Or is it too complicated? Would you then recommend to just use a different type of table than a Pivot and filter the results so it does not show the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
Range("D" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Total, '')"
```